# Kubernetes Metrics Server not responding

Tags: kubernetes

Has anyone run into this issue.

Autoscaling seems to have stopped working and I get the following error from any HPA I create

`Conditions:
  Type            Status  Reason                   Message
  ----            ------  ------                   -------
  AbleToScale     True    SucceededGetScale        the HPA controller was able to get the target's current scale
  ScalingActive   False   FailedGetResourceMetric  the HPA was unable to compute the replica count: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: unable to fetch metrics from resource metrics API: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)
  ScalingLimited  True    TooFewReplicas           the desired replica count is increasing faster than the maximum scale
rate
Events:
  Type     Reason                   Age                   From                       Message
  ----     ------                   ----                  ----                       -------
  Warning  FailedGetResourceMetric  53s (x17244 over 5d)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  unable to get metrics for resource cpu: unable to fetch metrics from resource metrics API: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)`

I checked the metric server logs and I get the following

`0529 14:54:33.749323       1 heapster.go:71] /metrics-server --source=kubernetes.summary_api:''
I0529 14:54:33.751589       1 heapster.go:72] Metrics Server version v0.2.1
I0529 14:54:33.752620       1 configs.go:61] Using Kubernetes client with master "https://10.96.0.1:443" and version 
I0529 14:54:33.752642       1 configs.go:62] Using kubelet port 10255
I0529 14:54:33.754452       1 heapster.go:128] Starting with Metric Sink
I0529 14:54:34.036240       1 serving.go:308] Generated self-signed cert (apiserver.local.config/certificates/apiserver.crt, apiserver.local.config/certificates/apiserver.key)
I0529 14:54:34.474364       1 heapster.go:101] Starting Heapster API server...
[restful] 2018/05/29 14:54:34 log.go:33: [restful/swagger] listing is available at https:///swaggerapi
[restful] 2018/05/29 14:54:34 log.go:33: [restful/swagger] https:///swaggerui/ is mapped to folder /swagger-ui/
I0529 14:54:34.476366       1 serve.go:85] Serving securely on 0.0.0.0:443
I0529 15:07:44.217338       1 logs.go:41] http: TLS handshake error from 10.36.0.71:40660: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
I0529 15:09:38.647544       1 logs.go:41] http: TLS handshake error from 10.36.0.71:41350: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake`

Not sure what is causing this as I did work up until last week.

kube version 1.10.3

Comment: Could you provide Heapster and HPA configurations?

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev I can’t now. I got frustrated and just did a reset of the cluster. Everything seemed up to date although we just updated and kube-dns also bailed on us so I think the two issues were somehow related.